# Finding a permutation from list<int> using linq

Tags: c#, linq

This seems like it would be easy, but I have bumped into one issue after another... I have a search algorithm that requires a permutation search. I have a sql database that serves up to a web service. In my controller I have a complex search algorithm, one of the search options is to find permutations of a data field.

The data would be a list of integers like [0,0,9,3,8,7,4]... The search criterion would also come in as a list of integers like [9,4,7]... in this case the permutation exists, and it the evaluation should return true in the linq query.

So I have been attempting to write a "boolean" function that would return true or false to evaluate if a permutation exists... So far my attempts have worked except in the case where example 2 and 3 below both return true... because they are evaluated because of the single Zero, not that there are a quantity of two zeros... if that makes sense?

```
[0,0,9,3,8,7,4] => [9,4,7] = true
[0,0,9,3,8,7,4] => [0,0,2] = false
[0,0,9,3,8,7,4] => [9,0,0] = true
```

I have tried "GroupBy", which will give me a list of keys and counts, which should work... right? in #1 does the array contain 9,4, and 7... for the other two, does the array contain, two zeros and the remaining number... this is always evaluating to true but is always evaluating that the search string contains a single zero not two zeros...

Can anyone assist?

Comment: As I've understood, it is actually not a permutation problem. You simply want to know if set B is a subset of set A.

Comment: would you share the code that you wrote?

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool IsPermutation(IEnumerable<int> list,IEnumerable<int> subList)
    {
        var grpListCnt = list.GroupBy(num => num).ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Count());
        var subGroupCount = subList.GroupBy(num => num).ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Count());

        foreach(var keypair in subGroupCount)
        {
            if (!(grpListCnt.ContainsKey(keypair.Key) && 
                              grpListCnt[keypair.Key] >= keypair.Value))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use simple `Linq` statement. Use `Any` and `All` extension and validate the combination.

```
// input
int[][] data = ...
int[] criteria = ...

bool matchFound =  data.Any(x=> criteria.All(c=> x.Contains(c));
```

In case if your source data is one dimensional array, you could simply use nested part (as shown below)

```
// input
int[] data = ...
int[] criteria = ...

bool matchFound =  criteria.All(c=> data.Contains(c));
```

Comment: why jagged array of data?

Comment: I pick it from OP's example, not sure completely. Worth mentioning other option as well, will update the question.

Comment: Why down vote? leave your comment we could improve answer.